# Restore MySQL from dump: different version and CHARACTER SET

Tags: mysql

I am moving data from my old database to my new one. The old DB uses:

```
MySQL version 5.5
CHARACTER SET utf8
```

I created a new database:

```
MySQL version 5.6
create database MY_DB;  -- Same name as old DB
ALTER DATABASE MY_DB default CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
Create some users, grant some privileges...
```

I want to create the db tables and add the data using a mysql dump file, but am concerned that the dump file will overwrite settings and variables that have been set in the new DB.

How do I:

- Write the dump command such that any wrong / unnecessary settings and the db create statement are not included? This includes DB and table level settings.

or

- Create tables and load data from the dump file, as is, and afterwards set all table and DB settings as they should be in the new DB?

These are the create statements and DB settings that I am seeing in the dump file:

```
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
    /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
    /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
    /*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;


    CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `MY_DB` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

    USE `MY_DB`;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MY_TABLE`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: Actually, what you want to do is a trial-and-error process. It depends on many factors, if one or other options are to be successfully or not. If you can juggle with the new db, then it's all already ok. But, if the new db already has data (and not from the old db !!), then you should really make all possible steps to 1) make a copy of it, so really a clone of it, 2) create a dump file from it and 3) make a copy of all the db/table files. Only after that should you begin the actual migrating process. Cont...

Comment: ...Cont: My choice would be the following: 1) Delete the new database. Run the dump file with all settings, 'create data' and 'create db' inside it. Then you'll notice how your system behave. If no evident errors/problems/crashes are raised, then it's good. Please notice that even the commentars inside dump file can produce errors. That's a version difference problem (/**/ against "--" comments). After that, manualy go through the settings of the new db and new tables. Pick 3-4 tables and study their settings, and especially the character set ones. Cont...

Comment: Don't change anything in the settings yet. Pick the same 3-4 tables and check some of their data for "strange" things. If all seems ok, then begin changing the settings like conversion from "utf-8" to "utf8mb4". Then go back and check the data again. If all seems good, then you are done. Try to resolve all problems even if you know that you'll have to delete the new db again. It's important to gain the knowledge of how to resolve them before trying other options. Now, if data is "corrupted" after all your changes, then you'll have to try something else. Cont:...

Comment: Hence your good proposed **OPTION 1**. Delete the new database again. And create it again. But per-hand this time. Set it to "utf8mb4" if you can. Edit your dump file beginning with deleting all from it, except the creation and settings of one table. Edit these ones, let the dump run and see the behavior, errors, etc. If all good, delete the one table again, but let the db be. Reedit dump file and change it overall with the "good" settings. Repeat the steps presented above. That's it.